# How to avoid escape character in awk

Tags: perl, shell, awk

This question is related to awk, I suppose.
I have no experience with awk. I tried lots of things but I could not find any solution.

Actually, I want to read a file line by line, then replace the whole line with perl.

I simplified the code. I hope you can understand.

```
new_line1=1234567
new_line2=1234/567

perl -pi -e "s/$new_line1/$new_line2/g" $FILE
```

The problem is that when I use is related to `/`.

```
Number found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/1234567/1234/567"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/1234567/1234/567"
```

Because bash assumes that `perl -pi -e "s/1234567/1234**/**567/g" $FILE`

How can I avoid it.

Comment: @TLP I assume that the OP wants to update the file in situ.  GNU `sed` offers this ability, but GNU `awk` doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different delimiter from `/` if you don't want to escape it:

```
perl -pi -e "s#$new_line1#$new_line2#g" $FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `awk` in the title...

The standard solution is to use a different delimiter.  Unfortunately, in awk you cannot do the intuitive thing and write `\@pattern@` to use `@` as a delimiter, but you can explicitly call `match`:

```
awk 'match( $0, "'$new_line1'" ) { print "'$new_line2'"; next } 1' $FILE
```

This does not work if either `new_line1` or `new_line2` contains a `"`.
Note that this does not edit the file in place.  (Neither does the `perl -i`, really, as it creates a new file.)